# Code coverage for UMD block in nodejs module

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, code-coverage, node-modules, chai

I've written a node module with UMD ([Universal Module Definition](https://github.com/umdjs/umd)) Pattern to make it compatible with amd and plain javascript as well.

The definition is as below

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory();
    } else {
        root.myModule = factory();
    }
}(this, function (global) {
    ...
    return {};
}));
```

With mocha & chai the tests are running fine, the only issue is that since the tests are executed from within node the code coverage for `define(factory);` and `root.myModule = factory();` lines is showing red.

Just wanted to know if there is any way(maybe a hack) to get 100% coverage for this code with mocha chai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!

How coverage tools for JS basically work, is that their injecting little bit of tracker code for each line. So what you need is that the execution flow wonders there.

Since this is an `if-else` logic, to get `100%` you will be needing multiple test scenarios to cover this.

**Note**: it's also important for actually achieving this effect, that loading that file (`factory`) should happen after every scenario setup, because that is when those `module-loading-if-else` lines are executed. Now this depends on what is your file/module loading in your test execution environment.

Now to enter into that `branch` of the `if-else` create a test scenario where you can just enforce the existence of that `define` function with a few lines like (e.g. in a `beforeEach` section):

```
define = function () {
  console.log('hello I am a fake define, but I will be defined ...');
  console.log(' ... so that if else branch will be executed.');
}

// and of course the needed .amd property.
define.amd = true;
```

I think the same weird stuff can be done w/ the `exports` variable, but it might be hard to achieve if you are just pure CommonJS `require`-ing that file, since `require`-ing defines the `exports` variable for that file context, so maybe you could modify your production code for this weird case. I wouldn't do that, but you said `any way`:

```
...
 } else if (typeof exports === 'object' && testExportsEnabled) {
...
```

Now using this you can just have one scenario where in `beforeEach` you do: `testExportsEnabled = true;` and w/ this being false, the last branch should be executed.

Of course you can execute all branches with such a simple trick! Now to have no code modification AND trigger the third branch (basically the case for simple `script-tag-loading` in browser), you will need to dig in into your module loading code and create some hacks there, but that is a bit too much for me in an SO question! :]

Take care!

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to know how to - `enforce the existence of that define function`. Since adding it in beforeEach isn't working

Comment: If you push a repro env to github I can take a look into the `define` part, that should be actually easy to make it work.

Comment: thanks. repo - https://github.com/vivekweb2013/toastmaker

Comment: I've created a PR: https://github.com/vivekweb2013/toastmaker/pull/1, added some comments so you'll understand the magic. After executing `npm run coverage` you will see amd/commonJS path as tested. (I've commented out the rest of the tests, they caused me too much noise)

Comment: sure thing. I advise u to dig into trying to pass the third branch as well. it will give u lot of insight in js module loading!